# How to update drupal 7.7 to 7.8 manually?

Tags: 7, updating

I found that there is a warning on my site saying that manual updates of Drupal core is required.

How can I do it safely?[image]

Answer (score 8):

See [this](http://drupal.org/node/1223018) article from the Drupal.org documentation under section "MINOR VERSION UPDATES".

> To update from one minor 7.x version of Drupal to any later 7.x
>   version, after following the instructions in the Introduction section
>   at the top of this file:
>
> 1. Log in as a user with the permission "Administer software updates".
> 2. Go to Administration > Configuration > Development > Maintenance mode. Enable the "Put site into maintenance mode"
>      checkbox and save     the configuration.
> 3. Remove all old core files and directories, except for the 'sites' directory, the original install profile in the 'profiles'
>      directory     and any custom files you added elsewhere.
> 4. Download the latest Drupal 7.x release from http://drupal.org/project/drupal to a directory outside of your web 
>      root. Extract the archive and copy the files into your Drupal
>      directory.
> 5. Re-apply any modifications to files such as .htaccess or robots.txt.
> 6. Run update.php by visiting http://www.example.com/update.php (replace www.example.com with your domain name). This will update
>      the    core database tables.
> 7. Go to Administration > Reports > Status report. Verify that everything is working as expected.
> 8. Ensure that $update_free_access is FALSE in settings.php.
> 9. Go to Administration > Configuration > Development > Maintenance mode. Disable the "Put site into maintenance mode" checkbox and save
>      the configuration.

Answer (score 4):

In short :

1. Replace all the files  with the 7.8-files (except the sites directory!)
   --> this will  take care of the file part
2. Run the update script (url/update.php). 
   --> this will take care of the database part

Since you haven't replaced the files-directory, all basic settings (settings.php) there should be ok.

That's the main principle in a minor update. Of course you always should take precautions like backups, and take care of all files outside the sites directory that might have changed.

For more info see  : see http://drupal.org/node/1223018